# scope variable updated in angular but change is not reflected to user

Tags: javascript, angularjs, scope

I have some angular variables set like so:

```
$scope.pane = [];
$scope.pane.count = 0;
$scope.pane.max = 5;
```

Then I display the variables in the HTML like this:

```
{{pane.count}}
```

This works fine and displays `0` as expected.

Now if I update the variable at any point, the update does happen (I can see using console.log) but the printed version in the HTML does not update.

E.g.

```
setTimeout(function(){
  $scope.pane.count = 1;
},1000);
```

I am using Angular v1.3. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Your `pane` should need to be `{}` object instead of array.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

In order to let angular know about changes, you have to use angular [wrapper](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$timeout) for timeout.

Try this:

```
$timeout(function() {
  $scope.pane.count = 1;
}, 1000);
```

Generally, when you have a structure outside angular world(such as jQuery plugin) that changes values, you have to call $scope.$apply() to let angular know about them.

```
$scope.$apply();
```

Comment: The setTimeout was just an example of the variable being changed. My script is actually more complex but the same issue applies (no setTimeout being used in my script).

Comment: @Coop The same logic applies. Any non-angular event must inform Angular that something has changed. Using `$timeout` applies to your example, but you could equally use $apply too

Comment: when you have a structure outside angular world(such as jQuery plugin) that changes values, you have to call $scope.$apply() to let angular know about them.

Comment: Awesome! I never knew about `$apply`. Thanks for that.

Comment: $scope.$apply(); Saved me hours !! :)

Comment: I was not at all aware about `$scope.$apply();`, 
most needed, thanks! +1

Comment: I get this error when I do `$scope.$apply();`:

`Error: [$rootScope:inprog] $digest already in progress`

Answer (score 3):

setTimeout is outside angularjs scope so you need to use $scope.$apply or $timout please see sample demo below

```js
var app = angular.module('app', []);

app.controller('homeCtrl', function($scope, $timeout) {

  $scope.pane = [];
  $scope.pane.count = 0;
  $scope.pane.count2 = 0;
  $scope.pane.max = 5;

  setTimeout(function() {
    $scope.$apply(function() {
      $scope.pane.count = 1;
    })

  }, 1000);

  $timeout(function() {
    $scope.pane.count2 = 5;
  }, 2000);


});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>


<div ng-app="app">
  <div ng-controller="homeCtrl">
<h3>setTimeout</h3>
    Count 1: {{pane.count}}<br/>
    <h3>$timeout</h3>
    Count 2: {{pane.count2}}
  </div>
</div>
```